# Interpreting python string(FIX) recieved over the network as binary

Tags: python, twisted, fix-protocol

I am sending a fix message over socket connection and recieving within a python client.
I know there is a SOH seperating each name=value pair in the data.
But the data when printed(as a string), does not show the SOH. The problem arises because I want to be able to show the '|' or I cannot tell within a regular expression, what the boundaries for the individual fields are.
I have looked at decode('hex'), decode('uu') on the recieved string , without much success.
Also the pack/unpack require that you supply a format string(which I would have to do for every type of fix).

I am using the Twisted ClientFactory for the client.

Any suggestions?

Follow Up Question:
I use the repr and pass it to a function to replace the '\x01' with '|'.
Now when I pass in the data recieved from the network directly, replace seems to have no affect. However when I copy the output and pass it as a string literal into the same function. It behaves as expected(replaces '\x01' with '|').
I also tried using a re.sub, with  exactly the same results( works when passed in as a string literal , but not when passed in directly from the network).
I also printed the value from the network into a file , and compared using  vi hex editor , to the string literal. It does not reveal any differences.

Some additional information:
When I print the value from a file and read it back, I am not able to use find on '\x01', implying that replace would not work either(it does not).
When I try to convert this into a byte array , it would appear that each of the '\' , 'x' , '0', '1' are interpreted as different bytes, when i iterate over the byte array. Which is strange. either the '\x01' is a string or its not and is hex.

Any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that replace using '\x01' works on the data coming in over the network(and not the output of repr). I am not sure what the reason is, but this meets my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Printing out repr as suggested by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, solves part of the problem.